# Wordpress: Use page variable with custom field inside WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

I have the following variable that I'm trying print in the tax query array section "term =>"... The field is a custom field attached to the page.

I can print **$value_variable** *before* the wp_query, but when I put it inside the array it does not print.

This is in a Wordpress environment.

```
$value_variable = the_field('categoria_de_slider');

$argumentsalojamientos1fa = array(
    'post_type' => 'slider_tours',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'asignar_slider',
            'field' => 'id',
            'term' => $value_variable
        )
    )
);
$queryalojamiento1fa = new WP_Query($argumentsalojamientos1fa); 

while($queryalojamiento1fa->have_posts()) : $queryalojamiento1fa->the_post();?>

 <?endwhile; ?>

// something happens  

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did further studies of my code and found 2 problems. The answer is not the answer to the question, because it was improper code what caused the problem.

1. The correct way is using get_field.

   ```
   $valuevariable = get_field('categoria_de_slider');
   ```
2. My tax query was wrong too, my $valuevariable value is the category term ID so I had to use "terms_id" and "terms".

   ```
   'tax_query' => array( 
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'asignar_slider',
           'field' => 'terms_id',
           'terms' => $valuevariable
       )
   );
   ```